# update yeoman package.json file

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I just created a new AngularJS application using yeoman. I noticed that in the package.json file that gets created most of the devDependencies are obsolete release candidates.
For instance `"grunt-contrib-copy": "0.4.0rc7"`, instead of `"grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1"`.
Is there a way to make these packages be the latest versions? Or do I manually have to state what version to use?

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Either you set

```
"grunt-contrib-copy": "latest"
```

in your template `_package.json` in your generator and you will always have the latest version of the package.

Either you make your generator trigger the shell command

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-copy
```

at the end of your Yeoman generation task with

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var BlogGenerator = module.exports = function BlogGenerator(args, options, config) {
  yeoman.generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);

  this.on('end', function () {
    exec('npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-copy', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      this.installDependencies({ skipInstall: options['skip-install'] });
    }.bind(this));
  });

  this.pkg = JSON.parse(this.readFileAsString(path.join(__dirname, '../package.json')));
};
```

and you will get the most recent version of the package persisted at the time of your project generation.

Comment: You should never use `latest` as it will definitely break at some point.

Comment: I totally agree but I don't see any problem with allowing somebody to initialize a new project with the latest release of a given dependency at project generation time (that's the second part of my answer). Then the version is fixed. It's like a shortcut to yo angular; npm info grunt; npm install --save-dev grunt#vX.Y.Z with X.Y.Z the last version I chose to use in my new project.

Comment: Using `latest` and initializing with the latest version are two different things. I'm obviously only contending the former, as it's a really bad practise and you shouldn't recommend people doing it.

Comment: I also don't understand your second point. Why would you go through all that trouble and not just edit the _package.json version to the latest version `npm view grunt-contrib-copy version` instead.

Comment: I don't know what is climboid exact context but I can easily imagine where I am working that people who are maintaining in house generators want that every time a new project is generated, for some dependencies, last versions are automatically chosen at generation time. It's a matter of in house processes and conventions. But I agree my answer is a little dirty in some ways. It was more about giving some technical orientations than giving some practical recommendations.

Answer (score 5):

You must be using a very old version of the Angular generator. [The latest one has all up-to-date dependencies](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/1a176e192b608cad5388670a6319c9d0f4930e70/templates/common/_package.json#L7).

You can update the generator with: `npm update -g generator-angular`.

If you want to bump the already generated version, just run `npm install -D grunt-contrib-copy`. You should also edit the `_package.json` in the generator so the deps are up to date the next time you generate.